# MVC session lost when creating and deleting folders

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, session

I am running a MVC4 asp.net app and it deals with create/delete folder inside the app folder.

The session stay when the app create or delete folders.

But the session was lost when the app create a folder then delete one after another.

I have place this snippet in Global.asax as a resolve to maintain the session even there are changes in the physical folder inside the app:

```
PropertyInfo p = typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", indingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
object o = p.GetValue(null, null);
FieldInfo f = o.GetType().GetField("_dirMonSubdirs", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
object monitor = f.GetValue(o);
MethodInfo m = monitor.GetType().GetMethod("StopMonitoring", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
m.Invoke(monitor, new object[] { });
```

Is there any way to fix this without moving the folder location outside the app folder?

Comment: There is a change in .NET 4.5.1 that breaks your file monitoring.  So, whenever you add or delete a folder, your ApplicationPool is restarting. Thus, your session is gone. Just a little background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could put your session in the database, and that would keep it alive.

"Configure SQL Server for ASP.NET SQL Server Session State" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

Edit: For Windows Azure, I would go for Windows Azure Cache. Refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx and https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/ I believe that would not be affected by recycling the application.

Or for a more generic solution, this using Microsoft ASP.NET Universal Providers might work: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers

Comment: The system might be deployed in an Azure environment and there are disadvantages when using SQLServer as a sesstionState mode in Azure and one is that Microsoft does not support SQL Session State Management using SQL Azure databases for ASP.net applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify anything inside the bin subfolder, the application will be recycled, which will cause an InProc session to be lost.

I wouldn't expect the application to be recycled if you create/delete folders other than bin, but you can easily check this by adding a trace statement to Application_End.  If this event is fired, your application is being recycled.

Application recycling following a modification to the bin directory is by design, and I wouldn't attempt to interfere with it by reflecting on private ASP.NET methods.

You could try using an out-proc SessionState mode (StateServer or SQLServer)